# Spark Sql Query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 4 columns in my dataset (user ,timestamp , ip , isadmin) .

Now i need to perform spark sql query operation on the above dataset . Lets assume the dataset variable name is myactivities.

My spark sql query should add new column called "event_hour" which is extracted from HOUR(timestamp) and then group by event_hour, user.

Below is the query i tried

```
myactivities.createOrReplaceTempView("hourly_sorted_activities");

Dataset<Row> sortedDataset = sparkSession.sql("SELECT Extract(HOUR FROM timestamp) as event_hour_window , user, timestamp, ip, isadmin FROM hourly_sorted_activities GROUP BY event_hour_window, user”);

Dataset<Employee> trimmeddataset = sortedDataset.as(Encoders.bean(Employee.class)
```

I am getting below error from above line 2 .

[main] ERROR com.x.x.x.xclass - 
missing ')' at 'FROM'(line 1, pos 20)

```
== SQL ==
SELECT Extract(HOUR FROM timestamp) as event_hour_window , user, timestamp, ip, isadmin FROM hourly_sorted_activities GROUP BY event_hour_window, user
--------------------^^^

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
missing ')' at 'FROM'(line 1, pos 20)

== SQL ==
```

Comment: Add sample data for more details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `extract` doesn't work this way, but it fails for me as well. (may be a version thing?) To extract the hour from your timestamp, use `hour(<ts column)`.

```
val foo = spark.sql(""" select current_timestamp as ts """)
foo.createOrReplaceTempView("fooView")
spark.sql("""select hour(ts) from fooVIew""").show
+--------+
|hour(ts)|
+--------+
|      10|
+--------+
```